# How to make Ubuntu useradd behave like Centos useradd?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, useradd

I don't remember modifying CentOS useradd to get this behavior.

`useradd` in CentOS creates the user's home directory with all the normal files (like `.bashrc`).

I modified `/etc/default/useradd` to make it looks like CentOS (just required some uncommenting) except for Ubuntu having `SHELL=/bin/sh` instead of `SHELL=/bin/bash`

How do I make useradd act like it does in CentOS? Is there some existing option to change? Or should I just add an alias to `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

The difference:
On Ubuntu, useradd is not creating the home directory.

as root:

```
$ useradd test
$ cd ~test
-su: cd: /home/test: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Having made you /etc/default/useradd the same on both systems - what is not working as you expect ?

Comment: Sorry, should have explained that! Editing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the line

```
CREATE_HOME yes
```

to `/etc/login.defs`

From the Ubuntu useradd man page

> -m, --create-home
>
> ...
>
> By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME is not enabled, no home directories are created.

Although the CentOS man page is more helpful as it says

> ... useradd will create the home directory unless CREATE_HOME in /etc/login.defs is set to no.

Comment: That's what I needed. Compared the `login.defs` on both systems and that was the difference. As soon as I changed it on the Ubuntu system, `useradd` started acting just like on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

On creating the home directory, useradd actually copies the directory /etc/skel. There for if you want to have some settings already added to new home folders its as simple as adding the files to /etc/skel and the next time you add a user, those files will be in the home directory.

*Edit*

Use useradd **-m** username
this works on both centos and ubuntu.

Comment: It's not even creating home directories.

Comment: You're right about the command line, but I wanted to change the defaults. lain's answer provides the correct location and environment variable.